# Postgres Join tables using timestamp (part of it)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, timestamp

I have data with a frequency of one minute for 3 years and I would need to put it in one table to make it comparable.

**Table1-2019**

| date_time | v_2020 |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2019 01:00:00 | 50 |
| 01.01.2019 01:01:00 | 49 |
| 01.01.2019 01:02:00 | 56 |

**Table2-2020**

| date_time | v_2020 |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 01:00:00 | 60 |
| 01.01.2020 01:01:00 | 59 |
| 01.01.2020 01:02:00 | 56 |

**Table3-2021**

| date_time | v_2020 |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 01:00:00 | 55 |
| 01.01.2021 01:01:00 | 54 |
| 01.01.2021 01:02:00 | 48 |

**requested table**

| date_time | v_2019 | v_2020 | v_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01. 01:00:00 | 50 | 60 | 55 |
| 01.01. 01:01:00 | 49 | 59 | 54 |
| 01.01. 01:02:00 | 56 | 56 | 48 |

[Visualisation of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN7iV.png)

I tried several codes, but they didn't work. With functions `JOIN` and `LEFT`, I have a problem with the format of date_time column (it is a `timestamp without zone`). With the `SUBSTR` I had also a problem with format of date_time.

Finally I tried code below, but it also doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE all AS
SELECT A.date_time, A.v_2019 FROM Table1 AS A
JOIN Table2
WHERE (select datepart(day, month, hour, minute) from A.date_time)=(select datepart(day, month, hour, minute) from Table2.date_time)
JOIN Table3
WHERE (select datepart(day, month, hour, minute) from A.date_time)=(select datepart(day, month, hour, minute) from Table3.date_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you create your tables run this query. I believe that it is straightforward:

```sql
select to_char(t1.date_time, 'mm-dd hh24:mi') date_time,
  t1.v_2020 v_2020_2019,
  t2.v_2020 v_2020_2020,
  t3.v_2020 v_2020_2021
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.date_time = t1.date_time + interval '1 year'
join table3 t3 on t3.date_time = t1.date_time + interval '2 years';
```

See [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5mH7q1rs37hXidNtU4Mj9/1)

| date_time | v_2020_2019 | v_2020_2020 | v_2020_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01 01:00 | 50 | 60 | 55 |
| 01-01 01:01 | 49 | 59 | 54 |
| 01-01 01:02 | 56 | 56 | 48 |

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have an additional question. How can I deal with the occasional missing value in some columns? For example for 01-01 01:01 there will miss v_2020_2020 but still, I would have a row with this time.

Comment: @beginner Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. Left, right, and inner join are represented often as a venn diagram. There is also `OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with an `INTERVAL` I think you should consider a `JOIN` condition that uses date manipulating functions.

Keep in mind using something like `WHERE DATE_TRUNC(...)` or `JOIN ... ON DATE_TRUNC(...)` will NOT respect indexes on these fields. When passing the field value into a function you're essentially creating a black box that cannot take advantage of an index. You would need to create an index specifically on `DATE_TRUNC('DAY', date_time)` for example.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-aZmKYe7) is another DBFiddle for you to consider

You can do this in a couple ways:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(v19.date_time, 'MM-DD HH24:MI') datetime
     , v19.v_2019
     , v20.v_2020
     , v21.v_2021
  FROM t_2019 v19
  FULL JOIN t_2020 v20
    ON DATE_PART('MONTH', v19.date_time) = DATE_PART('MONTH', v20.date_time)
   AND DATE_PART('DAY', v19.date_time) = DATE_PART('DAY', v20.date_time)
   AND v19.date_time::TIME = v20.date_time::TIME
  FULL JOIN t_2021 v21
    ON DATE_PART('MONTH', v20.date_time) = DATE_PART('MONTH', v21.date_time)
   AND DATE_PART('DAY', v20.date_time) = DATE_PART('DAY', v21.date_time)
   AND v20.date_time::TIME = v21.date_time::TIME
;
```

---

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(v19.date_time, 'MM-DD HH24:MI') datetime
     , v19.v_2019
     , v20.v_2020
     , v21.v_2021
  FROM t_2019 v19
  FULL JOIN t_2020 v20
    ON TO_CHAR(v19.date_time, 'MM-DD HH24:MI') = TO_CHAR(v20.date_time, 'MM.DD HH24:MI')
  FULL JOIN t_2021 v21
    ON TO_CHAR(v20.date_time, 'MM-DD HH24:MI') = TO_CHAR(v21.date_time, 'MM.DD HH24:MI')
;
```

---

Both of these result in the following:

| datetime | v_2019 | v_2020 | v_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01 01:00 | 50 | 60 | 55 |
| 01-01 01:01 | 49 | 59 | 54 |
| 01-01 01:02 | 56 | 56 | 48 |